# "the regular expression pattern is not valid" while replacing a regex with an array

Tags: regex, powershell

In the code below I'am trying to replace a part of a css file that is not functioning well with a css file that holds the right code.

At part 1 I obtain both files.

At part 2 I filter the invalid part from bad.css with a regex.

At part 3 I want to replace the bad css with the good.css file. However I get the error "the regular expression pattern is not valid".

One should note that `$b` is a type of Array and `$d` is a type of String. But I do not really know if it makes a difference.

```
#1. get files
$overrider = (Join-Path $powerShellResourcePath "good.css")
$b = Get-Content $overrider

$stylingOverride = (Join-Path $contentPath "bad.css")
$c = Get-Content $stylingOverride

#2. gets the part that should be replaced in bad.css
$d = [Regex]::Matches($c, '(start)(.*?)(end)') | Select -ExpandProperty Value 

#3. should replace the regex part in bad.css with the whole good.css
if ($d) {
  $c = $c -replace $d, $b
  Set-Content $stylingOverride -Value $c
}
```

Comment: What is the value in `$d` when you replace? Maybe you just need to escape it - `[Regex]::Escape($d)`. Also, `start` and `end` are part of `$d`, right? Maybe you need to exclude the delimiters from it, `'(?<=start).*?(?=end)'`

Comment: the value of `$d` is everything between start and end. I have tried  `[Regex]::Escape($d)` and it did indeed fixed the error. However nothing changed in the css file.

Comment: That is because of the `start` and `end` in the value. Try `Matches($c, '(?<=start).*?(?=end)')`

Comment: Does that work now? Again, what does `$d` hold?

Comment: does not seem to work. `$d` holds everything inbetween start and end without start and end.  However when i check `[Regex]::Escape($d)` it gives the same value but with a lot of escape characters. And I think because of that he cannot find it back in `$c`

Comment: Ok, then your question is unclear. What is the value of `$d`? What is inside `$c`? What is in `$b`? Sorry, without exact input and required output a regex question has little sense.

Comment: Inside `$c` we can find all the lines of css from bad.css.
Inside `$b` we can find all the lines of css from good.css. 
Inside `$d` we can find all the lines of css from bad.css that need to be changed. So in `$d` we can find the regex filtered css.

Comment: You cannot pass an array of patterns and an array of replacements to a regex replace (at least I think so). You need to process them in a kind of a loop.

Comment: That might work, I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the extracted string, so you match the literal (sub)string:

```
$c = $c -replace [regex]::Escape($d), $b
```

Alternatively use the `.Replace()` method instead of the `-replace` operator. The former does simple string replacements whereas the latter does regular expression replacements.

```
$c = $c.Replace($d, $b)
```